ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv_lstm1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 300, 17)
I need help to figure out what I am missing in this code.
This is the model:
def make_model(input_shape):
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(input_shape)

    convLSTM1 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=32, kernel_size=sfreq, strides=2, padding="valid")(input_layer)
    convLSTM1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(convLSTM1)
    convLSTM1 = keras.layers.ReLU()(convLSTM1)

    convLSTM2 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=64, kernel_size=sfreq, strides=2,padding="valid")(convLSTM1)
    convLSTM2 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(convLSTM2)
    convLSTM2 = keras.layers.ReLU()(convLSTM2)

    convLSTM3 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=128, kernel_size=sfreq, strides=2,padding="valid")(convLSTM2)
    convLSTM3 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(convLSTM3)
    convLSTM3 = keras.layers.ReLU()(convLSTM3)

    gap = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(convLSTM3)

    output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(gap)

    return keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)


model = make_model(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:])
model. Summary()

I got this error: I know it has to do with the input and output dimension but, I am having challenges in figuring out what needs to be added to fix this error.
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv_lstm1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 300, 17)


There is a type in your code
convLSTM2 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=64, kernel_size=sfreq, strides=2,padding="valid")(conv1)

should be
convLSTM2 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM1D(filters=64, kernel_size=sfreq, strides=2,padding="valid")(conv1LSTM1)

similar typo in layer 3 code as well

The typo has been fixed, but I am still having the same error as before

Can you please provide the shape of the input_shape

This is the shape (1018, 300, 17)

If data_format="channels_first": 4D tensor with shape: (samples, time, channels, rows)
If data_format="channels_last": 4D tensor with shape: (samples, time, rows, channels)

So it should be (None, 1018, 300,17)
